# QAudioInput::byteReady() and QIODevice::read() giving different number of bytes

Tags: qt, qt4.8

I am having a doubt with the following code snippet…

```
const qint64 bytesReady = m_audioInput->bytesReady();
const qint64 bytesSpace = m_buffer.size() - m_dataLength;
const qint64 bytesToRead = qMin(bytesReady, bytesSpace);
const qint64 bytesRead = m_audioInputIODevice->read(m_buffer.data() + m_dataLength, bytesToRead);
```

bytesReady() method is giving me a particular number of bytes and am passing these number of bytes to the read() of QIODevice which will return me the number of bytes read.

The problem is that bytesRead is not equal to bytesToRead.
And am getting fixed number of bytes from read method i.e 320, 640, 960, 1280, etc. and this depends on byteToRead.

Comment: Can you try it in a loop? ie `while(bytesReady = m_audioInput->bytesReady()  >0 ){...}` and tell what happens? How did you initialized the QAudioFormat in use? did you made sure that `QAudioDeviceInfo::isFormatSupported()` returns true??

Comment: everything works fine the problem is with the above code snippet... not actually a problem but a doubt because my code is running successfully..

Comment: when do you read? do you use QIODevice::readyread() signal??

Comment: yes m using readyRead() signal..

Comment: Obvious question, but `bytesSpace > bytesReady`, right?

Comment: yes koying its always greater...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no direct relation between the `QAudioInput::bytesReady()` and the `QIODevice` on which it is writing its samples.

`QAudioInput` maintains internally a IO device (system dependent) to the audio system, which is analog to a read-only `QIODevice`. 
When you call `bytesReady`, it returns the number of bytes available to be read, analog to `QIODevice::bytesAvailable()`. Those have **not** yet been written to the output `QIODevice`, so when you do the `m_audioInputIODevice->read` just after it, without processing events, you're actually getting the samples which have been written earlier, not the ones still in the audio buffer.

This, plus the buffering of the IODevice, explains why the numbers might be different, and I don't see a way to synchronize them together.

Actually, you should do:

```
const qint64 bytesRead = m_audioInputIODevice->read(m_buffer.data() + m_dataLength, bytesSpace);
```

to get whatever is available from the IODevice, up to your available buffer space.

Comment: regarding this...  "When you call bytesReady, QAudioInput has not yet written the samples to the IODevice, so when you do the m_audioInputIODevice->read, you're actually getting older samples."

Comment: First read will give you whatever `QAudioInput` has already written to the output QIODevice from the time you did the `void QAudioInput::start ( QIODevice * device )`

Answer (score 2):

Better yet:

Use `->readAll()` which returns a `QByteArray` "qba"

...then use `sz=qba.size()` which will tell you what you GOT (may be zero)

...then do something with it using `sz` and `qba.data();`

...seems to be without bugs unlike much of `QAudioInput`, which is incredibly broken, for instance, arbitrary sample rate limit of 48000 under Windows but not OSX, pull mode uses foreground thread so will break up constantly in any real situation, `bytesReady()` is meaningless... Worst. Qt. Routine. Evar!